# How to implement mraid.js MRAID 3.0 in android?

Tags: javascript, android, ads, mraid

Is there any standard mraid.js file required to implement MRAID compliant ads in android or do i need to implement my own mraid.js from reading the MRAID 3.0 specification?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's none.

Notice MRAID implementation is not only `mraid.js` - mraid.js is just a javascript [bridge](https://iabtechlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/MRAID_3.0_FINAL_June_2018.pdf) between HTML5 ads and SDK Native code. So even if there were, it wouldn't mean you can just borrow it and plug into your SDK as is - you'll still have to implement the code on your SDK's side.

To see real-world implementations you might check out any open-source SDK i.e. [Appnexus Android SDK](https://github.com/appnexus/mobile-sdk-android) that does support MRAID - not sure about MRAID3 though but I've seen MRAID2 support there.